# How do I get records from the database for a particular interval?

Tags: sql, mysql, django

My table has records for every minute, now I want to fetch records with an interval of 5 minutes!

For instance

```
order date
 1    12:01
 2    12:02
 ....

 10   12:10
 11   12:11
```

Expected result: Order 6 and 11

Can it be done at database level?

I am using Django with MySQL

Comment: Could you add an example of what data you want to retrieve ?

Comment: In what way interval of 5 minutes?

You want every 5 minutes to generate a recordset or you want to fetch records from a specific 5 minute interval?
(Thank you for pointing it out Ignacio :D)

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question, it is very confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SomeModel.objects.extra(select={'fiveminutes': 'MINUTE(date)%5=0'},
  where='fiveminutes=1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to group orders based on the twelve five minute intervals in an hour?  By five minute intervals, I mean a minutes to interval mapping like this: (0..4 => 0, 5..9 => 1, 10..14 => 2, ...).

```
all_with_interval = SomeModel.objects.extra(
        select={'interval': "strftime('%%M', date)/5"})
just_minutes_5_to_9 = all_with_interval.extra(
        where=["interval=%d"], params=[0])
```

Or maybe you want a five minute range from an given start_time:

```
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
start_plus_5_inclusive = SomeModel.filter(date__range=(start_time, end_time)
start_plus_5_exclusive = start_plus_5_inclusive.exclude(end_time)
```

The exclude() is there because the [range filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) is inclusive and you probably want to exclude the end_time for this current question.  If you do not exclude end_time you could get records in a 5 minute + ~1 second time range.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want,

eg every 5th record in the table?  Or to put it another way each record where order is divisible by 5?

I am doing this from my head as I dont have a mysql db here to play with

```
SELECT * from Table where (order MOD 5) = 1;
```

(= 1 will give you divisible by 5 +1 so 6, 11, 16 etc)

Try that and see if you wet what your looking for.

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) for more on MOD function